# dynamically populating array with html content without stripping tags

Tags: php, html

I have some HTML Content.

Eg.

```
<p>Ask a question</p><p>Wait for an answer</p><p>Vote up an Answer</p>
```

I want to use php to input each paragraph/div or any other html element separately as elements of an array

```
$arr[0]="<p>Ask a question</p>";
$arr[1]="<p>Wait for an answer</p>";
```

I want to do the above task dynamically.

Comment: so. what have you tried? how did it go?

Comment: i have tried breaking it down using explode but it removes the tag, i have even looked up regex but couldn't get any leads.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this. My first approach would be to use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

Assume your html is in `$html`:

`preg_match_all( '|<p>.+?</p>|si', $html, $matches );`

`$matches` will then be an array-of-arrays of 1 element x N elements, where N is the number of matches.

```
$matches[0][0] == '<p>Ask a question</p>';
$matches[0][1] == '<p>Wait for an answer</p>';
...
```

**Edit**: this can be generalized to match other tags, but a DOM parser should be used instead after the complexity requirements outweigh what regular expressions are capable of parsing.

If you want to match a fixed set of non-nestable tags, this approach will work, but if the desired tags are nestable or self-closing, then regular expressions are not the way to go and using a simple DOM parser will be the right solution.

Comment: if there are other html tags beisde 'p', can you give a regex to match these other tags also?

Comment: can i do the above task using php simple DOM parser?

Comment: Yes, using a DOM parser is one approach, and it's typically the "correct" approach. [Using regular expressions for general parsing of HTML is evil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), but I will generally use that technique over a full parser because it's generally simpler if you have fixed criteria.